# WCF and Threading

Tags: multithreading, wcf

I have one WCF service and in one module i have to send confirmation mails on every save of the records. I am planning to use asynchronize threading for sending the mails so that service performance does not get affected when mail is send.

My question is whether using threading in WCF is safe or it may impact its performance?

Answer (score 1):

How many emails are you sending as part of a save? If it's only a small number (ie: 1), the threading isn't necessary. Sending mail from .net to a local SMTP server (which will handle the actual delivery) is very fast. The actual "work" of doing delivery is handled by the SMTP server and isn't something you need to worry about.

You can do it and it should work, but in this case IMO the simplest solution will give you the best (and most easily maintainable later) results.

Comment: Thanks Tridus, but what if i use async thread in wcf, does it can impact the performance? I am asking this because quantity of mail can be higher

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm also not sure it'll help. If the request itself returns before that thread is finished, it may very well be aborted. And if you have to wait for it anyway, you're not gaining anything by using a thread to do it. You'd have to check it to find out.